# Grails find by property

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Okay, I am trying to find all of my `Employee` that have a given role...  However no matter what I try I end up getting the same exception thrown...

```
enum Role {
  SFC("State Fitness Coordinator"),
  TRAINING("Training"),
  DFC("District Fitness Coordinator"),

  final String longName

  private Role(String longName) {
    this.longName = longName
  }
}


class Employee {
  static hasMany = [roles: Role]  
  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

The first Thing I tried was `Employee.findAllByRoles(Role.DFC)`

Then I tried:

`Employee.findAll("FROM Employee e WHERE e.roles IN (:role)", [role: [Role.DFC]])`

as well as

```
Employee.withCriteria {
  'in'('roles', [Role.DFC])
}
```

all resulting in

`Class
    java.sql.SQLException
Message
    Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1`

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Role.DFC.longName` instead of just `Role.DFC`? So in the first example, `Employee.findAll("FROM Employee e WHERE e.roles IN (:role)", [role: [Role.DFC.longName]])`

Comment: @grantmc that gives the same error but... the Roles are saved in the database with the enum name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with grails 2.3.8 and H2

```
Employee.findAll("FROM Employee e WHERE :role in elements(e.roles) ", [role: Role.DFC.toString()])
```

this works… even if I think that Role could be a real Domain simplifying all operations

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Role is an enum. Are you sure you want to make it an enum?

**I recommend making it a class since new roles might be added. If so, you can easily add a record using bootstrap or SQL query without making a new build to production.**

```
class Role {

     String roleName
     String description
}
```

In Bootstrap:

```
Role sfc = new Role("SFC","State Fitness Coordinator")
Role sfc = new Role("TRAINING," "Training")
Role sfc = new Role("DFC", "District Fitness Coordinator")
```

N.B. Please make sure you are not using *spring security plugin* which has its own 'Role' class. If so, please change the name of your 'Role' class to something like 'EmployeeRole'